# Discord-Modals failing on phones. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a game ban appeal, using the `Discord-Modals` package, and it seems to work good so far, however, the modal looks odd on phones, which will be a problem.

There are no errors, Here is what it looks like:

[On PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKZ6V.jpg), and On [Phone1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoLHt.jpg) [Phone2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY4J5.jpg)

As you can see, [On PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKZ6V.jpg) there was the `Do you think the ban was fair?` select drop down, but on both phones, it wasn't there.

I'm not sure of this is fixable, but I sure hope it is.

Code:~

```js
// Main requirements
const { CHANNEL_SSU, CHANNEL_ROLESEL, BOT_PREFIX, ROLE_DEV } = require('../../config.json')
const commandName = '2gba'

// Optional Requirements
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageCollector, InteractionType } = require('discord.js')
const { Modal, TextInputComponent, showModal, SelectMenuComponent } = require(`discord-modals`)

// Main Code
module.exports = client => {
    client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(BOT_PREFIX)) return;

        const command = message.content.split(' ')
        const args = message.content.substring(1).split(' ')

        if (command.toString().toLowerCase().replace(BOT_PREFIX, '').startsWith(commandName)) {
            if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(ROLE_DEV)) return message.reply("Only Developers can use this command!")

            const buttonsRow1 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('GBAempty5')
                .setLabel('  ')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(true),
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('GBA2')
                .setLabel('Appeal')
                .setStyle('DANGER')
                .setDisabled(false),
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('GBAempty6')
                .setLabel('  ')
                .setStyle('SECONDARY')
                .setDisabled(true)
            )

            const GBAEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Appeal Your Game Ban! 222')
            .setColor('DARK_BLUE')
            .setFooter({ text: 'ASRP | System Bot' })
            .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 }))

            message.delete()
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [GBAEmbed], components: [buttonsRow1] })
        }
    })
    client.on(`interactionCreate`, async (interaction) => {
        if (!interaction.isButton) return
        
        if (interaction.customId == 'GBA2') {
            const modal = new Modal()
                .setCustomId(`gbamodal`)
                .setTitle(`ASRP | Game Ban Appeal`)
                .addComponents(
                    new TextInputComponent()
                    .setCustomId("RobloxUsername-gba")
                    .setLabel("Roblox Username")
                    .setStyle("SHORT")
                    .setMinLength(1)
                    .setPlaceholder('Please check for any typos.')
                    .setRequired(true),
                    new TextInputComponent()
                    .setCustomId("Moderator-gba")
                    .setLabel("Who banned you?")
                    .setStyle("SHORT")
                    .setMinLength(1)
                    .setPlaceholder('This field is optional.')
                    .setRequired(false),
                    new TextInputComponent()
                    .setCustomId("unbanreason-gba")
                    .setLabel("Why should we unban you?")
                    .setStyle("LONG")
                    .setMinLength(1)
                    .setPlaceholder('Give us a reason to unban you.')
                    .setRequired(true),
                    new TextInputComponent()
                    .setCustomId("banreason-gba")
                    .setLabel("Why were you banned from asrp?")
                    .setStyle("LONG")
                    .setMinLength(1)
                    .setPlaceholder('Give us the reason you were banned for.')
                    .setRequired(true),
                    new SelectMenuComponent()
                    .setCustomId('fair-gba')
                    .setPlaceholder('Do you think your punishment was fair?')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                        label: "Yes",
                        description: "You think the punishment was fair.",
                        value: "Yes",
                        emoji: "✅"
                        },
                        {
                        label: "No",
                        description: "You think the punishment was unfair.",
                        value: "No, I think it's unfair.",
                        emoji: "❌"
                        }
                    )
                );

                showModal(modal, {
                    client: client,
                    interaction: interaction
                })
        }
    });

    client.on('modalSubmit', async modal => {
        if (modal.customId === 'gbamodal') {
            const RBXuser = modal.getTextInputValue('RobloxUsername-gba');
            let BanMod = modal.getTextInputValue('Moderator-gba');
            if (!BanMod) BanMod = 'None Stated';
            const ReasonUnban = modal.getTextInputValue('unbanreason-gba');
            const ReasonBan = modal.getTextInputValue('banreason-gba');
            const Fairness = modal.getSelectMenuValues('fair-gba');

            const user = modal.user
            const appealEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`New Game Ban Appeal`)
            .setAuthor({ name: `User: ${user.tag} (${user.id})` })
            .addFields(
                {name: `Q: Roblox Username`, value: `A: ${RBXuser}`},
                {name: `Q: Who banned you?`, value: `A: ${BanMod}`},
                {name: `Q: Why should we unban you?`, value: `A: ${ReasonUnban}`},
                {name: `Q: Why were you banned?`, value: `A: ${ReasonBan}`},
                {name: `Q: Do you think the ban was fair?`, value: `A: ${Fairness}`}
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `This is beta, please report any errors.` })
            .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 }))

            await modal.reply({ content: 'Your submission was recieved successfully!', ephemeral: true }).then(() => {
                client.guilds.cache.get(`954881682429853726`).channels.cache.get('998833987810246666').send({ embeds: [appealEmbed] });
            })
            console.log(modal.getTextInputValue('RobloxUsername-gba'))
            console.log(modal.getTextInputValue('Moderator-gba'))
            console.log(modal.getTextInputValue('unbanreason-gba'))
            console.log(modal.getTextInputValue('banreason-gba'))
            console.log(modal.getSelectMenuValues('fair-gba'))
        }
    });
}
```

```css
Extra Information:
Node Version: 'v16.14.2'
NPM Version: '8.5.0'
Discord.js Version: '^13.7.0'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If discord.js has a responsive modals just like on normal html modals, yes it can be fixed, but if there's non. Then sad to say you can't do anything about it

Comment: Damnit, do you think this will be fixed when it officially comes out on 14v?

Comment: discord.js supports modals natively. Also, select menus are not fully supported in modals yet, which may be issue

Comment: Yeah, I see that, thanks for helping, make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Menu's within Modals are unsupported and not documented by Discord - this is not a user issue nor an issue with the code.

Select Menu's just don't show up on mobile and only partially work within Modals (as of August 2022).